# Lua & C++ : running a dynamic snippet?

Tags: c++, qt, lua

I have a Lua thread running, and a Qt-powered text edit running in parallel. I want the user to be able to run any Lua code he has written in the text edit, but it doesn't work well. It works with simple instruction(s), like "print(5)" or "tmp = 5; print(tmp)" but it doesn't work with strings (print( "hello world") ) or numeric expressions like print(5+3).
And, worst of all, it doesn't work if I try to call a lua function defined before or a C registered function.

If I delete signals&slots etc, my code is roughly this :

```
const char* text = textEdit->toPlainText().toLatin1().data();
luaL_loadstring(_LuaState, text);
lua_pcall(_LuaState, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);  ///These 2 lines used to be luaL_doString,
// but it didn't work
```

the Lua State is the same that the one where I registered C functions and loaded a lua file defining some others functions

Comment: You throw away the error message. Print it.

Comment: What means "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Indeed printing error is helpful. (What I meant by "doesn't work" was "nothing happens, but an error I didn't catch")
Still, I don't understand all the errors I get :

print("Hello world") works well, but print("Hello ") gives this : 
**Loadstring fail : [string "print("Hello ")"]:1: unfinished string near <eof>
pcall fail : attempt to call a string value**

print(5+3) gives : 
**Loadstring fail : [string "print(5+3)"]:1: unexpected symbol
pcall fail : attempt to call a string value**

Comment: Check what `text` variable contains just before calling loadstring.  Probably, newlines have been inserted or somehow text was mangled?  Does `text` contain zero-terminated string or not?